# How to prevent loading same image twice

Tags: javascript, background-image

These codes are fine. It loads the image for calculation of dimension and then add to new image tag.

```
var img = new Image();
var box = $('picBox');

img.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width;
    var h = this.height;    
    box.appendChild(img);       
};
img.src = image_url;
```

But in the routine below, It seems the same image was loaded twice. Once for calculation of dimension and another for set background-image. Is there way to do it as above. Thanks in advance.

```
var img = new Image();
var box = $('picBox');

img.onload = function() {
    var w = this.width;
    var h = this.height;    
    box.setStyle('background-image', 'url('+image_url+')');
};
img.src = image_url;
```

Comment: I think you mean for `$('picBox');` to be something like `$('.picBox');` or `$('#picBox');`

Comment: In mootools, $('picBox'); is fine, same as $$('#picBox'). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work okay using MooTools. [Tested it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzWkL/1/). If you open your console and watch, it only logs the data once. Also, used `.setStyles()` and object notation to adjust the element's width and height:

```
box.setStyles({
    'background-image': 'url(' + image_url + ')',
    'width': w,
    'height': h
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The second time it will load it from browser cache, so you don't have to worry about it.
You can open network inspector in firebug to sniff all requests that are being sent and you will see that second time it is returning "Not modified" headers for that image.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, `F12` will open up the dev tools and the Network tab will show what Arsen is pointing out.

Comment: But somehow the first routine is twice as faster, at least in Chrome. Thanks! btw, your answer means that there is no other way?